# Filter JavaScript object by value in a key value array

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array

I have this object of data

```
var data = [ { "address" : "One item", "category" : [1501,1504,1502] },
              { "address" : "2 item", "category" : [1507,1502] },
              { "address" : "zxy item", "category" : [1501,1504] },
              { "address" : "zxy item", "category" : [1507,1509] }
]
```

I would like to filter out the objects that do not have the `category id` of `1502` and return the new data array like this below. Sometimes the `category` array has one or more category ids in it.

```
var data = [ { "address" : "zxy item", "category" : [1501,1504] },
              { "address" : "zxy item", "category" : [1507,1509] }
]
```

Vanilla javaScript answers requested. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily filter the array using [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and select only the object that doesnot [includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) the `1502`

```js
var data = [{
    address: "One item",
    category: [1501, 1504, 1502]
  },
  {
    address: "2 item",
    category: [1507, 1502]
  },
  {
    address: "zxy item",
    category: [1501, 1504]
  },
  {
    address: "zxy item",
    category: [1507, 1509]
  },
];

const result = data.filter((obj) => {
  return !obj.category.includes(1502);
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [`Array#includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes):

```js
const data = [ { "address" : "One item", "category" : [1501,1504,1502] }, { "address" : "2 item", "category" : [1507,1502] }, { "address" : "zxy item", "category" : [1501,1504] }, { "address" : "zxy item", "category" : [1507,1509] } ];

const res = data.filter(({ category = [] }) => !category.includes(1502));

console.log(res);
```

Comment: Why does my console respond with i.category is null?

Answer (score 1):

You can try using [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to filter the items that does not [`includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)the number in the current category:

```js
var data = [ 
  { "address" : "One item", "category" : [1501,1504,1502] },
  { "address" : "2 item", "category" : [1507,1502] },
  { "address" : "zxy item", "category" : [1501,1504] },
  { "address" : "zxy item", "category" : [1507,1509] }
]
data = data.filter(i => !i.category.includes(1502));
console.log(data);
```

Comment: Why does my console respond with `i.category is null`?

Comment: @omukiguy, it is possible only for the category item in the array on which you are implementing the code have the value *null*:)

Answer (score 0):

A more versatile solution could be a closure over the wanted key and the value and get a function for the callback without having a hard wired value to search.

```js
const
    data = [{ address: "One item", category: [1501, 1504, 1502] }, { address: "2 item", category: [1507, 1502] }, { address: "zxy item", category: [1501, 1504] }, { address: "zxy item", category: [1507, 1509] }],
    includes = key => value => object => object[key].includes(value),
    categoryIncludes = includes('category'),
    result = data.filter(categoryIncludes(1502));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```